# How to determine the effect of manufacturing variability on assembly of items

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, process-engineering, statistics, quality-engineering, production-technology

Any help is appreciated. Below are some details

1. The product has around 20 different components (including ones manufactured to spec, fasteners, off the shelf, consumables, etc.)
2. Lets assume the production volume would be 500 units/year.

I need help with:

1. How do I determine the effect of variability of Key Components (manufactured to spec) on the assembly of product.
2. How large should the sample size be, and how to determine that?
3. How to relate 95% confidence & 95% reliable in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

A professional statistician can tell you what sample size is required to achieve 95/95, but note that a yearly production volume of 500 units means about 2 units/day. This means statistical quality control will be extremely difficult to achieve because your sample sizes will be tiny. You will need a completely different quality control paradigm: 100% functional test of EVERY UNIT BUILT. I can explain this off-line; contact me at www.nielsenkillowatt if you wish.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Based on my research for a medium risk product to achieve 95/95 a sample size of around 60 is required.  As yearly production is only 500 units, I am unable to justify producing 60 units pre-production to study manufacturing variability. The purpose of this validation is to avoid future issue in the assembly due to variability in the components due to their tolerances.  Yes, 100% functional test on every unit built is expected at this stage.